# Class for Strong References in Java, for anonymous classes

Tags: java, reference

I want a hard reference ***class*** in my Java code, but, of course, there isn't one.  Is there some other way to do what I want, or should I make my own class?

This comes up with anonymous classes in methods where I want the anonymous class to set the return value for the method.

For example, given

```
interface Greeting {
    void greet();
}
```

I want code like the following:

```
// Does not compile
static void hello(final String who) {
    String returnValue;

    Greeting hello = new Greeting() {
        public void greet() {
            returnValue = "hello" + who;
        }
    };
    hello.greet();
    System.out.println(returnValue);
}
```

I can fake it using a list:

```
static void hello(final String who) {
    final List<String> returnValue = new ArrayList<String>();
    Greeting hello = new Greeting() {
        public void greet() {
            returnValue.add("hello" + who);
        }
    };

    hello.greet();
    System.out.println(returnValue.iterator().next());
}
```

But I want to not use a list.  I can write a `StrongReference` class that solves this:

```
static class StrongReference<T> {
    private T referent;
    public void set(T referent) {
        this.referent = referent;
    }
    public T get() {
        return referent;
    }
}
```

which makes my method clearer:

```
static void hello(final String who) {
    final StrongReference<String> returnValue = new StrongReference<String>();
    Greeting hello = new Greeting() {
        public void greet() {
            returnValue.set("hello" + who);
        }
    };

    hello.greet();
    System.out.println(returnValue.get());
}
```

For my contrived example, I could have `greet()` return a String, but I'm working with much more complex classes, where the setting is deep within a database call that the base class manages.  The instances have many different types they want to return, so I've just been using the `List` trick.

My questions are:  Is there a better way to do this?  What's wrong with my `StrongReference` class?  Has anyone written a `StrongReference` in a library somewhere?

Comment: I don't understand what's the advantage of your 'List trick' over your 'StrongReference'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want something from the standard API, perhaps an [`AtomicReference`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) would do?

It has `void set(V value)` and a `V get()` methods. Unless you have multiple threads involved, just see the synchronization mechanism as a bonus ;-)

Comment: Interesting. Sounds weird to me though. I would assume that a call to `get` would return the value set through the closest preceding `set`. How can this be guaranteed without synchronization?

Comment: Cool, that's what I was looking for.  I don't actually need the thread safety, because the variable is on the stack and this method doesn't spawn multiple threads.  But it's worth it for using a standard class.  (and if I recall, `AtomicReference` is very quick)

Answer (score 4):

A common idiom

```
final String[] result = { null };

result[0] = ...;
```

Comment: Yes, that's cleaner than my list approach.  Presumably faster as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good but I think you should make some kind of synchronization since another thread might set the value.